# SQL Server Reporting Services regularly unresponsive until IIS Reset or Application Pool Recycle

Tags: iis, reporting-services, timeout

I'm afraid I'm at wits end here, so hopefully someone can at least point me towards the right idea.

I'm currently running Reporting Services 2005, SP4, using IIS 6.0, on a Windows Server 2003 SP2 machine.

The issue that I'm facing is that, very regularly, the website where the reports are delivered (localhost/reports and the equivalent using the machine name for non-internal access) becomes completely unresponsive. The page is stuck loading, and never completes.I

I found a pseudo-solution to the problem recently. If I recycle the application pool associated to the reporting services IIS page, the website responds again - but only for a short time, after which it becomes unresponsive again. Restarting IIS also resolves the problem, but again, only for a short time.

I've checked the windows application logs, the IIS logs associated to the reporting services webpage, and the reporting services logs - none of them provide me with any additional information as to why this is happening.

Has anyone experienced this before? I have absolutely no idea where to look next.

Comment: I would check/tune the database queries driving the reports. It sounds like they are slow and are tying everything up. It also sounds like when you recycle the app pool, things are freed up [because query connections are closed] until you start running reports again.

Comment: It's not the database - even accessing pages on the reporting services website which don't call a report are unresponsive. And there are not many concurrent accesses. If I look at the IIS logs, the site becomes unresponsive even when it is only me accessing it. Also, running a trace against the database server shows that the queries aren't even reaching the database.

Comment: You are running on such an old stack - you should probably consider an upgrade of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I may have solved the problem *crosses fingers*.

Basically, just deleted all the IIS websites and all the IIS application pools except the Default Application Pool. Then, went into the Reporting Services configuration manager, and reset all the configurations back to their defaults. Restarted the website, and lo and behold, the problem doesn't seem to be arriving.

No idea why this worked, but ...